# Why onPress function doesn't Work?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript-2

Here is my code :

```
stop();

btn_start.onPress = function() 
gotoAndStop("gameon")
```

I have An error and it sounds like: "

```
Access of possibly undefined property onPress through a Reference with static type 
flash.display:SimpleButton.
```

I converted the text into a Button, I gave him an id, I don't know what to do, don't judge, I'm begginer.

Thanks!

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. If you can't get useful code in your question from your phone, then you might want to wait until you can get to a computer and enter it properly, because there's no way to figure anything out from what you've provided here.

Comment: Just " ;" "{" That i've missed, is about onPress function, doesn't Work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem is that your are trying to use the `ActionScript 2`'s `onPress()` function inside an `ActionScript 3` code which didn't support that kind of functions.

In ActionScript 3 you should use [event listeners](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e54.html) to catch an event on an object.

In your case, you can use, for example, a `MouseEvent.CLICK` event listener like this :

```
btn_start.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, on_Press);

function on_Press(e:MouseEvent): void
{   
    gotoAndStop('gameon');
}
```

And for more about migration from ActionScript 2 to ActionScript 3, take a look [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/first_as3_application.html).

Hope that can help.

Comment: Thank you! It was very usefull!

Comment: Please @CalinOnaca, mark the akmozo answer as the right answer.